# qemu passthrough stopped working

Tags: boot, bash, 17.10, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I've been working on setting up a Windows vm with gpu Passthrough on Ubuntu 17.10 through qemu the last couple of days. The farthest I've gotten was running a very similar script to this:

```
#!/bin/bash

vmname="betterwin10vm"

if ps -A | grep -q $vmname; then
echo "$vmname is already running." &
exit 1

else

# use pulseaudio
export QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=pa
export QEMU_PA_SAMPLES=8192
export QEMU_AUDIO_TIMER_PERIOD=99
export QEMU_PA_SERVER=/run/user/1000/pulse/native

cp /usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_VARS.fd /tmp/my_vars.fd

qemu-system-x86_64 \
-name $vmname,process=$vmname \
-machine type=pc,accel=kvm \
-cpu host \
-smp 3,sockets=1,cores=3,threads=1 \
-m size=4G \
-mem-path /dev/hugepages \
-mem-prealloc \
-balloon none \
-rtc clock=host,base=localtime \
-vga none \
-nographic \
-serial none \
-parallel none \
-soundhw hda \
-usb -usbdevice host:1532:0214 -usbdevice host:1532:0043 \
-device vfio-pci,host=04:00.0,multifunction=on \
-device vfio-pci,host=04:00.1 \
-drive if=pflash,format=raw,readonly,file=/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_CODE.fd \
-drive if=pflash,format=raw,file=/tmp/my_vars.fd \
-boot order=dc \
-drive if=virtio,id=disk0,cache=none,format=raw,file=/dev/sdb1 \
-drive file=/home/keith/Downloads/lubuntu-17.10.1-desktop-amd64.iso,index=1,media=cdrom \
-drive file=/home/keith/WIN_VM/virtio-win-0.1.141-2.iso,index=2,media=cdrom \

exit 0
fi
```

that yesterday allowed me to run lubuntu and later the windows10 install (until it couldn't install my virtio drivers) in the VM I am planning to use for windows. Today, I cannot even boot into the iso, nor can I display even the bios on my secondary monitor plugged into the GPU (04:00.0). The only way I can see that nothing is booting is when I disable the `-vga none` property and allow qemu to run in windowed. My mouse and keyboard also get attached to the VM, so I know it is on. Although I have no explanation of why my iso is not booting, when I run `dmesg | grep vfio` , I get this lengthy (shortened) response repeated multiple times.

```
[    2.303445] vfio-pci 0000:04:00.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=none
[    2.320128] vfio_pci: add [1002:67df[ffff:ffff]] class 0x000000/00000000
[    2.344187] vfio_pci: add [1002:aaf0[ffff:ffff]] class 0x000000/00000000
[ 2805.815146] vfio-pci 0000:04:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
[ 2805.835195] vfio-pci 0000:04:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
[ 2805.855139] vfio-pci 0000:04:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
[ 2806.583096] vfio-pci 0000:04:00.0: timed out waiting for pending transaction; performing function level reset anyway
[ 2807.771124] vfio-pci 0000:04:00.0: Failed to return from FLR
[ 2807.773191] vfio_cap_init: 0000:04:00.0 hiding cap 0xff
[ 2807.773194] vfio_cap_init: 0000:04:00.0 hiding cap 0xff
[ 2807.773198] vfio_cap_init: 0000:04:00.0 hiding cap 0xff
[ 2807.773201] vfio_cap_init: 0000:04:00.0 hiding cap 0xff
[ 2807.773336] vfio_cap_init: 0000:04:00.0 hiding cap 0xff
[ 2807.773339] vfio_cap_init: 0000:04:00.0 hiding cap 0xff
[ 2807.795138] vfio-pci 0000:04:00.1: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
[ 2807.815138] vfio-pci 0000:04:00.1: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
[ 2807.835154] vfio-pci 0000:04:00.1: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
[ 2808.567093] vfio-pci 0000:04:00.1: timed out waiting for pending transaction; performing function level reset anyway
[ 2809.755122] vfio-pci 0000:04:00.1: Failed to return from FLR
[ 2809.757190] vfio_cap_init: 0000:04:00.1 hiding cap 0xff
[ 2809.757194] vfio_cap_init: 0000:04:00.1 hiding cap 0xff
[ 2809.757197] vfio_cap_init: 0000:04:00.1 hiding cap 0xff
[ 2809.757200] vfio_cap_init: 0000:04:00.1 hiding cap 0xff
[ 2809.757204] vfio_cap_init: 0000:04:00.1 hiding cap 0xff
[ 2809.757207] vfio_cap_init: 0000:04:00.1 hiding cap 0xff
[ 2809.757331] vfio_cap_init: 0000:04:00.1 hiding cap 0xff
[ 2809.757334] vfio_cap_init: 0000:04:00.1 hiding cap 0xff
[ 2809.757337] vfio_cap_init: 0000:04:00.1 hiding cap 0xff
[ 2809.831139] vfio-pci 0000:04:00.1: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
[ 2810.583131] vfio-pci 0000:04:00.1: timed out waiting for pending transaction; performing function level reset anyway
[ 2811.771126] vfio-pci 0000:04:00.1: Failed to return from FLR
[ 2811.791130] vfio-pci 0000:04:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
[ 2812.535123] vfio-pci 0000:04:00.0: timed out waiting for pending transaction; performing function level reset anyway
[ 2813.723127] vfio-pci 0000:04:00.0: Failed to return from FLR
[ 2945.935092] vfio-pci 0000:04:00.1: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
[ 2946.679158] vfio-pci 0000:04:00.1: timed out waiting for pending transaction; performing function level reset anyway
[ 2947.867152] vfio-pci 0000:04:00.1: Failed to return from FLR
[ 2947.887159] vfio-pci 0000:04:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
[ 2948.631161] vfio-pci 0000:04:00.0: timed out waiting for pending transaction; performing function level reset anyway
[ 2949.819151] vfio-pci 0000:04:00.0: Failed to return from FLR
[ 3692.523889] vfio-pci 0000:04:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
[ 3692.543829] vfio-pci 0000:04:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
[ 3692.563836] vfio-pci 0000:04:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
[ 3693.307807] vfio-pci 0000:04:00.0: timed out waiting for pending transaction; performing function level reset anyway
[ 3694.495843] vfio-pci 0000:04:00.0: Failed to return from FLR
```

Could this possibly have anything to do with my issues? If so, how should I deal with this? Thanks :)